# How to test RichFaces combobox with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, richfaces, webdriver

We have an application based on RichFaces 3.3.3 . We have created automated tests with Selenium IDE that run fine. Since the RichFaces comboboxes are not real html comboboxes but an input field with a bunch of javascript, in Selenium we need to select a value with the following trick:

```
type      field_id "field value"
typeKeys  field_id "field value"
fireEvent field_id "blur"
```

In order to integrate the tests into our continuous integration system, we have transformed the test to jUnit tests that use WebDriver (Selenium 2.5.0) as the backend. Unfortunately the combobox trick stopped working.

All type and typeKeys commands are translated as shown below:

```
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [fireEvent]]
driver.findElement(By.id("patientCreateDataForm:patientBirthDateInputDate")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("patientCreateDataForm:patientBirthDateInputDate")).sendKeys("16.06.1910");
```

Does anyone have any working solution to test RichFaces combobox elements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

1. click in the RichFaces combobox
2. select the item (male or female) and copy path with help FirePath
3. thereafter use Actions method in jUnit test. In the following example, button parameter is a combobox button id, element parameter is selected items xpath:

   ```
    private void comboboxSolution(String element, String button) {
       WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id(button));
       btn.click();
       WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
       Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       builder.moveToElement(myElement).click().perform();

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
typeKeys field_id "field value"
waitForVisible (look with firebug at the id of the div that becomes visible after typing)
click (look with firebug at the id of the entry you want to select)
waitForNotVisible the_id_of_the previous_div
```

I have this solution working for a rich:suggestionbox component, it should be easily adaptable for a combobox.

Comment: This seems like a selenium solution. We have no problem with selenium, but if we export the test cases to WebDriver jUnit scripts, they do not select the elements from the comboboxes. I have updated the issue with the generated webdriver code.